# Objective-C - How to set image received from JSON in UIImageView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview

I received the following response from JSON:

```
{
    age = 42;
    city = Berlin;
    country = Deutschland;
    distance = "4.58";
    "full_name" = Klaus;
    gender = Male;
    id = 654;
    online = 0;
    profile = "Klaus.png";
})
```

I'm using the following code to change the image in the `UIImageView`.

```
 NSString *imageURL = [[_responsedic valueForKey:@"profile"]objectAtIndex:0];

_TopList_ImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]]];
```

I wish to set the profile value from the JSON in the `UIImageView`, but the code did nothing. Appreciate any help, thank you in advance.

Comment: your profile picture path is missing ... it should be like http://www.*****.com/yourimage.png

Comment: invalid image url. it should be : www.apple.com/home/iphone.png

Comment: You must have online link to image like www.asd.com/images/Klaus.png after it you can download it easily

Comment: but this response in working on android

Comment: here is the API "http://tattoosingles.net/webservice/tattoosingles.php"

Comment: pls check with image url is missing ,tell to the server side guy..

Comment: @BajrangSinha check with sever side guy..

Comment: ok guys i got the URL of images i.e, http://tattoosingles.net/uploads/XmakeyourselfX.png

Comment: how to set it in UIImageView

Comment: @BajrangSinha  see below answer..

Answer (score 2):

try this..

```
  NSString *imgURL = @"imagUrl";
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgURL]];

    //set your image on main thread.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [YourImgView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
    });    
});
```